# Facebook Debugger Tool always replies 404 error

Tags: debugging, facebook-opengraph

Does anyone know, why the debugger tool (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) always reports a 404 error on the following link: [www.rosenhof-tirol.at/top-angebote-sommer.html](http://www.rosenhof-tirol.at/top-angebote-sommer.html)? The source code view of the page clearly shows the tags, which are reported missing. The CMS in use is Contao (www.contao.org). Other pages I implemented, do not have this problem. [Link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=www.rosenhof-tirol.at/top-angebote-sommer.html). Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Kind regards
Wolfgang

Answer (score 0):

The debugger reports a 404 error because your page is sending a 404 header.

[image]

Comment: ok i can see that, too. but, can you tell me why the page still shows in the browser? and there is not a 404 error page?